# Can't stick my footer to the end of the page

Tags: html, css

I am currently learning CSS & HTML and have a bit of trouble. My footer doesn't want to stick to the bottom; it floats above the bottom with space under it (like it had a margin on the bottom, even though it doesn't). I tried with most of the tips I found online, but most of them either don't work or make the header behave weird when the windows are resized (sometimes it puts it in the middle etc.)

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pooblaščeni Prodajalci</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="photos/adidas.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/trgovine.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="tm-header">
        <div class="tm-container">
            <a href="index.html"><img class="tm-logo"src="photos/adidas.png" width="80px" height="" alt="logo"></a>
            <nav class="tm-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li class="hover_menu"><a href="index.html">Domov</a></li>
                    <li class="hover_menu"><a href="about.html">O nas</a></li>
                    <li class="current_page"><a href="#">Pooblaščeni Prodajalci</a></li>
                    <li class="hover_menu"><a href="index.html">Storitve</a></li>
                    <li class="hover_menu"><a href="index.html">Kontakt</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="tm-container">
        <div class="tm-content">
            <section>
                <article>
                    <h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 50px;">Naši pooblaščeni prodajalci</h1>
                    <div>
                        <span class="trgovine"><a href="https://www.superge.si/" target="_blank"><img src="photos/superge_logo.png" alt="superge_logo" width="509px" height="200px"></a></span>
                        <span class="trgovine"><a href="https://www.hervis.si/store/" target="_blank"><img src="photos/Hervis_logo.png" alt="hervis_logo" width="509px" height="200px"></a></span>
                        <span class="trgovine"><a href="http://sl.sportsdirect.com/" target="_blank"><img src="photos/sports-direct-logo.png" alt="sportsdirect_logo" width="500px" height="200px"></a></span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span class="trgovine"><a href="https://www.intersport.si/shop/" target="_blank"><img src="photos/intersport_logo.png" alt="intersport_logo" width="509px" height="200px"></a></span>
                        <span class="trgovine"><a href="https://www.prva-liga.si/" target="_blank"><img src="photos/prva-liga-logo.jpg" alt="prvaliga_logo" width="509px" height="200px"></a></span>
                        <span class="trgovine"><a href="http://www.decathlon.si/" target="_blank"><img src="photos/decathlon_logo.png" alt="decathlon_logo" width="500px" height="200px"></a></span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span class="trgovine"><a href="https://www.tomassport2.si/" target="_blank"><img src="photos/tomassport-logo.png" alt="tomassport_logo" width="509px" height="200px"></a></span>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tm-footer">
        <footer>
            &copy; copyright Adidas 2017
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
body {
    background-image: url('../photos/background.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.tm-container{
    max-width: 1600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.tm-container{
    max-width: 1600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.tm-header{
    background: #fff;
    height: 64px;
}
.tm-logo{
    padding-left: 50px;
    float: left;
}
.tm-nav {
    float: right;
}
.tm-nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.tm-nav ul li a{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #303030;
    line-height: 64px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: right;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.tm-container ul li a:hover{
    color: #000000;
    text-shadow: 1px 0 0 currentColor;
    border: 1px solid #303030;
}
.current_page a{
    pointer-events:none;
    font-weight: 900;
}
p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
ul, ol{
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.tm-content{
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.tm-article{
    background-color: white;
    padding: 30px;
}
section {
    background-color: white;
}
.trgovine img{
    border: 1px solid blue; 
    max-width: 33%;
    width: 27%;
    margin-right: 3%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: in-line;
}
.tm-footer{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 30px;
    clear: both;
}
```

Here is a picture of how it actually looks:
[The arrows show the space below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4Azf.png)

EDIT: It´s not a duplicate, as the duplicate´s solutions don´t solve this problem

Comment: I'm not certian zzzBov grasps your issue... though based on what you provided, he might be on the right track.  I set up a quick fiddle and I found no issue with the code you provided.  Whenever something like this has happened to me it has been because there were some strange characters in my HTML file that the browser was attempting to display, resulting in unexpected space being taken up on-screen.  Try viewing your markup in another text editor like NPP or in a hex editor to check for a Byte Order Mark or other aberrant character that could cause this.

Comment: I might actually redo the page from scratch tomorow, making the footer at the start to see what the issue is...

Answer (score 0):

You need to update this line of code:

See live demo here: https://output.jsbin.com/nopetiy

```
.tm-footer{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 30px;
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: disagree.  this is a hack solution

Comment: this is the solution that acts weird for me (displaying the footer in the middle of the screen when resizing)